# How can I change the OAuth consent screen email address for my project?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-platform

I have a project I'm developing for my company and I have a personal company email address (myname@mycompany.com) as well as a "group" (AKA mailing list/distribution list) that is (support@mycompany.com).  I want to use my support@mycompany.com email address to show with the "OAuth consent screen" prompt for the end user.

The problem is no matter what `Role` I give the support@mycompany.com (other than `Owner` because it will not let group accounts be owners on a project) I can not get the support@mycompany.com email address to show up in the `Email address` field.

How can I get my `group` email to show up in the email address field?  Surely I don't need to pay a monthly fee (creating an unused account) just to change my OAuth consent screen email address...

Comment: Hi Arvo! I'm an engineer at Google. We've heard the feedback on this and we're working to improve it. I'll update this question once the solution is available.

Comment: @Patrick thanks!  Can't wait!  ;)

Comment: The solution is available today. See my answer below. I hope it provides what you were looking for!

Answer (score 5):

From the help text on the API Manager > Credentials > Oauth Consent Screen page:

> On some platforms, the email address is shown with the developer info. It can only be changed to the email of the signed-in user.

I think you'll have to log into the Cloud Console as the support@mycompany.com email address and change it there.

Comment: Yea that would have been my first thing to try IF I could.  You can't "logon" to a "group" email account.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you can select a Google Group email address that you own or manage as the email address in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=_). In the email address drop-down, there is a section titled "Google Groups managed by you".

Comment: Works, created google group, added it to project with role Editor, and email showed in dropdown.

Comment: Patrick, very much appreciate the help. I unfortunately can't seem to get this working. I've got a project tied to a GSuite domain, with a group created in that domain that I'd like to add as the contact on the OAuth Consent Screen. I've added that group a both a project Editor, and Owner, but the group fails to show up under the list of groups I can select under the "Email address" field. Are there any other special permissions / settings I need to make this work?

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet? Same as the others, i have added a group user, given him permissions as editor but it does not appear under 'google groups managed by you'

Comment: @chucky The solutions is available now. Please let me know if you are having issues and I can investigate further.