# Unable to set a group email as the email address for Google credentials "OAuth consent screen"

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-platform

This question is related to "[How can I change the OAuth consent screen email address for my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090280/how-can-i-change-the-oauth-consent-screen-email-address-for-my-project)", but unfortunately i didn't find my answer there. I also couldn't find details I needed from Google's documentation.

My IT department has created a group for me, and has shown me that myself and others are indeed owners of the group. I have added the group as an "Editor" of my project. However, I do not see the group in the email drop-down on the credentials OAuth consent screen settings:

[OAuth consent screen email drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tH6Q.png)

My question is: Are there certain settings that must be applied to the group for that group to be able to be selected in that consent email drop-down?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This tipped me in the right direction. I could see some email groups there but not the one I needed. It turned out I was not an owner and therefore it did not show up. Once I made myself an owner of the relevant group - it appeared in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IT department was able to fix the issue. In the google admin panel, they enabled the **Information > Directory > Group Directory** for the group.

["Group Directory" setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kBQZ.png)

After that, the group showed up in the "Google groups managed by you drop down". It seems that this external visibility was needed for this group to be used as the contact information for the OAuth consent screen.